# Magneto 2 limiter value sorting

Tags: magento2, module

**When i change the limit value, i really want to send the same value to all pages**

[image]

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ProductList/Toolbar.php

```
public function getLimit()
    {

        $limit = $this->_getData('_current_limit');
        if ($limit) {
            return $limit;
        }

        $limits = $this->getAvailableLimit();
        $defaultLimit = $this->getDefaultPerPageValue();
        if (!$defaultLimit || !isset($limits[$defaultLimit])) {
            $keys = array_keys($limits);
            $defaultLimit = $keys[0];
        }

        $limit = $this->_toolbarModel->getLimit();
        if (!$limit || !isset($limits[$limit])) {
            $limit = $defaultLimit;
        }

        if ($limit != $defaultLimit) {
            $this->_memorizeParam('limit_page', $limit);
        }

        $this->setData('_current_limit', $limit);
        return $limit;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be change by replacing the following code in
Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/toolbar/limiter.phtml

```
<select id="limiter" data-role="limiter" class="limiter-options">
            <?php foreach ($block->getAvailableLimit() as $_key => $_limit): ?>
                <option value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_key ?>"<?php if ($block->isLimitCurrent($_key)): ?>
                    selected="selected"<?php endif ?>>
                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_limit ?>
                </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
 </select>
```

with

```
<?php foreach ($block->getAvailableLimit() as $_key => $_limit): ?>
        <a data-role="limiter" href="#" data-value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_key ?>"<?php if ($block->isLimitCurrent($_key)): ?>
            class="selected"<?php endif ?>>
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_limit ?>
        </a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: dose not work and i don't want this